# Delphi command line build (DCC32) error: System.pas not found

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

Delphi 6 Professional in Win7/x64, with c:\Delphi6 folder.

Because the ProjectGroups are making OM errors, we need to build the projects one by one.

To provide faster compilation I tried to use DCC32.exe.

I found some info in this site about "extend dcc32.cfg with 4 options to set the library paths". 
I set each of them to the "Delphi/Options/Env. options/Library path".

Then I tried:

dcc32.exe b "any.dpr"

But I got error: System.pas don't found.

I don't understand it - maybe the dcc32.exe want to BUILD the basic pas files too, or I need to use another format.

We need to BUILD each of the projects, because we are using many conditional directives.

Thanks for the every info, suggestion you will write.

Comment: run sysinternals process monitor, filter by file i/o and process name "dcc32.exe" then try your compilation and see which folders it tries for system.dcu and system.pas

I bet you better put the paths in delphi project file (any.dof in pre-MSBuild Delphi, if my memory serves me) and do it as absolute paths without any environment vars like `$(Delphi)`. You might copied from IDE strings liek that and you'd better use fulli-qualified paths without any substitution. *PS there are also tools for building like want.exe and lazy builder*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not specifying the various paths on the command line, they need to be in a .cfg file. My dcc32.cfg file for Delphi 6 looks like this:

```
/LE"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi6\Projects\Bpl"
/LN"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi6\Projects\Bpl"
/U"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi6\Lib";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi6\Imports"
/R"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi6\Lib"
```

I have this in the Delphi `bin` directory. I put it there because it is specific to one particular machine since it uses absolute paths.

Obviously you might need to add some more paths to what I have above, but the above will get you what you need for the basic RTL/VCL units.

Comment: @Arioch'The I'm assuming that durumdara has enough intelligence to substitute the paths that work on his machine

Comment: That was it! I must set /I too, but I got the good result. Only one thing I search for - can I set the dcc32 to use another config file (in my global directory)? Thanks!

Comment: @durumdara Modify dcc32.cfg in the Delphi bin directory to effect global settings. However, if you do this you need to make sure that there isn't one in the current directory since that one would be chosen over the global one. It's all explained in the DCC32.CFG file topic in the D6 help file.